# Migrate Apache Cassandra to Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, aws-sct

I want to migrate the database from Apache Cassandra to Amazon DynamoDB.
I am following this user guide
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/agents.cassandra.html

When I try to create a clone data centre for extraction it throws
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you read through that document, you'll find that the conversion tool supports very old versions of Cassandra: 3.11.2, 3.1.1, 3.0, 2.1.20.

There will be a lot of configuration items in your `cassandra.yaml` that will not be compatible with the conversion tool including `replica_filtering_protection` since that property was not added until C* 3.0.22, 3.11.8 ([CASSANDRA-15907](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15907)).

You'll need to engage AWS Support to figure out what migration options are available to you. Cheers!

Comment: I am using cassandra 3.0.22

Comment: Exactly. `replica_filtering_protection` was added in C* 3.0.22 but the Dynamo DB conversion tool only supports 3.0.0 according to the document you linked so it doesn't know about that property. Cheers!